# Update Tkinter Label from function

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, usb

I have created a setup of an Arduino nano, which is connected to an ultrasonic sensor, and a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. The Arduino is triggering and reading the ultrasonic sensor, and sending data every 0,1 second over USB. Everything is ok with the connection, and i get results when i talk to the Arduino over the Python Shell. Now I wanted to create a nice Python GUI, to read the Distance, here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import serial

DEVICE = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
BAUD = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(DEVICE, BAUD)
root = Tk()
labeldat = IntVar(value=1)
def getdata() :
    labeldat = 0
    while labeldat == 0 :
        labeldat = ser.readline()
    root.update_idletasks()

root.title("Abstandsmessung mit Ultraschall")
Label(text="Der Abstand zum naechsten Objekt betraegt:",   fg="#0A116B").pack()
Label(root, textvariable=labeldat, fg="#0A116B").pack()
Button(text='Hole Abstand!', command=getdata, background="#33D63B",    fg="#FFFFFF").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Now I get the first label with the "Der Abstand zum naechsten Objekt betraegt:" and second label with text: "1". Of course I am also getting a Button which is labeled with "Hole Abstand!".
The Problem is, that when I click the button nothing happens. How can I update the Label every time when `labeldat` is changed?

Thank you for helping me,
Best regards
Armin

Comment: Apologies dear Sir, but you do realize that for many of us the words "Der Abstand zum..." mean nothing. Not everyone is German after all. I suggest you translate those errors if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-defining `labeldat`, (which by the way you aren't *actually* doing because you don't declare that you are referring to the global variable), just use `Tkinter.IntVar.set()`:

```
def getdata() :
    labeldat.set(0)
    while labeldat.get() == 0 :
        labeldat.set(ser.readline())
    root.update_idletasks()
```